# My active window is "underneath" the XFCE panel (eg. toolbar). How to fix this?

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

Thanks in advance for your help!  Please see the attached screenshot.  I don't want the XFCE panel/toolbar to overlay my active window.  I want the active window to expand up to the bottom border of the panel, but not go underneath it.  Notice how the tabs in my Chrome are covered by the panel.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have this problem, I have found that it only happens with Chrome (so far) when I maximise it using a keyboard shortcut (currently assigned to `super+up`) - if I maximise it with the maximise icon, it doesn't happen. "Don't reserve space on borders" was already unchecked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the panel preferences (accessible by right click on the panel) make shure that "Don't reserve space on borders" is unticked as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Okay, have done so. Still broken just like OP. Fresh install of MX Linux.

Comment: If the "Don't reserve space on borders" option in the panel preferences is unticked and it still doesn't work, try going in MX Tweak and make sure that the "Display panel horizontally" is selected as "Top". [MX Tweak screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G9lf.png)